# what is maximum HTML5 video resolution

Tags: html5-video

I am finding out whether HTML5 supports 4k resolution.
What is the maximum HTML5 video resolution supported? 
 
Does it support 4K videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HTML5 supports 4K video. In fact, YouTube supports 4K video through their HTML5 video player, however, it is important to note that not all hardware supports 4K video format. For example: if a user has a 1080p display, of course, their display will not be able to render anything with a resolution greater than 1080p.

So yes, HTML 5 itself supports 4K video, however 4K video playback may be limited by the user's hardware and/or software, so it is generally necessary to provide fallback options for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The resolution of a display will not restrict the resolution of videos that can be played. For example, if you play a 1080p video on a 720p screen, it will simply be downscaled. But yes, many computers and internet connections will still struggle with 4K video and it should absolutely not be the default.

Comment: I already knew HTML5 supports 4k but i still have the same question
"what is maximum HTML5 video resolution?"